# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyhash

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install a package `pyhash`, using `pip install pyhash` and it gives me the following error:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyhash
> (from versions: 0.6.2, 0.6.3, 0.8, 0.8.1, 0.8.2, 0.8.3, 0.9.0, 0.9.1,
> 0.9.2, 0.9.3) ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyhash

What does this error mean? By "version" do they mean "python version"? If so, how can I check which python versions pyhash is compatible with?

Answer (score 0):

I tried here with python3 and python2 and it installed just fine.
A lot of the times this is just a problem with your pip version. Ensure that it's updated with:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

And try again.

**Edit:**

Apparently pip version 21.3.1 uses `setuptools>=58` and `setuptools>=58` breaks support for `use_2to3`:

[setuptools changelog for v58](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/history.html#v58-0-0)

`use_2to3` it's a package used by pyhash to convert it's code.
So the better solution here I think would be to downgrade pip to version 21.2.4 with:

```
pip install --upgrade pip==21.2.4
```

Comment: It doesn't change anything after trying pip install pyhash again. Your command gives me the following: `Requirement already satisfied: pip in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (21.3.1)`

Comment: You're using windows? And virtualenvironments?
Just to try to replicate the error here

Comment: Using linux (ubuntu), and I have conda installed.

Comment: @user56834 Try using pip version 21.2.4, I did some tests here and it worked, I editted my answer to give the full explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing that has helped for was updating [setuptools](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/):

```
pip install -U setuptools
```